# How to solve the error "Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs"

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am getting the following **error**:

> Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new
>   Firebase Authentication SDKs available from
>   firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Though I have included recent version firebase authentication in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
```

This code was working fine in one my firebase project. But after adding this into another project in firebase,I'm facing the error.Please help me out.

```
            myFirebaseRef.createUser(
                    doctor.getEmail(),
                    doctor.getPass(),
                    new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
                            doctor.setId(stringObjectMap.get("uid").toString());
                            doctor.saveUser(myFirebaseRef);
                            Doctor_info doc=new Doctor_info();
                            doc.setGender(gender);

                            myFirebaseRef.child("doctor_info").push().setValue(doc);

                            myFirebaseRef.unauth();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Account has been Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Login With your Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            finish();
                        }
```

Comment: did you try using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method ? This is an example by [google](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java)

Comment: I have tried this too. I am always getting "Authentication failed." error

Answer (score 3):

Projects that are created at firebase.google.com, can only use the Firebase Authentication SDKs available from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/.

You're using a Firebase 2.x SDK, specifically this [`createUser()` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html#section-creating-accounts).

The fact that you're including a dependency on the new Firebase is not enough, you likely also have a dependency on Firebase for Android 2.x somewhere (e.g. `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'`), which you'll need to remove.

Comment: If I remove 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+' what will happen to my Firebase object?  that are importing  com.firebase.client.Firebase;

Comment: What to do if I don't want to use new SDKs?

Comment: If you already have an existing project on the legacy Firebase console, you can continue to use that with the 2.x SDKs. But projects that are created at firebase.google.com, can only use the Firebase Authentication SDKs available from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen This error also happens on server applications using Firebase 2. The funny part is applications create using Firebase Legacy and migrated to to Google Firebase work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem so:

1. "[Upgrade your Android app from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)"
2. Press in console "Add Firebase to your Android app"
   [image]