# Create user in firebase with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm using AngularJs and I want to create an user in firebase, then I wrote the following code, however it isn't working!

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);
myApp.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'MY_FIREBASE_URL');
myApp.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$firebaseAuth', 'FIREBASE_URL', function($scope, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
  $scope.headerTitle = "Registration Form";
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  $scope.register = function() {
        auth.$createUser({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        }).then(function(regUser) {
          $scope.message = $scope.user.firstName + " " + $scope.user.lastName + " " + "welcome !";
        }).catch(function(error) {
          $scope.message = error.message;
        });
  }
}]);
```

I get the following error when submit form : `Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/`

Comment: and i get the following error when submit form :

 Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010536/how-to-solve-the-error-projects-created-at-console-firebase-google-com-must-use. You'll need to use version 2.x of AngularFire.

Comment: i try version 2.0.1 of angularFire but not working and throw following error in the console : ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined

Answer (score 1):

For Firebase 3.x and AngularFire 2.x you have to **Initialize the Firebase SDK** by adding the **code snippet** to your html file.

1) **Copy** the code snippet

- Go to your Project Firebase Console https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
- in the main page of your project, click on *Add Firebase to your web app*
- in the popup, copy the code snippet, it may look like this:

  ```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          apiKey: " ** your key ** ",
          authDomain: "your-domain.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://your-domain.firebaseio.com",
          storageBucket: "your-domain.appspot.com",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  ```

2) **Paste** the code snippet in your html file.

- Paste the snippet at the bottom of your HTML or before other script tags.

have fun!

Comment: i use it but in console show following error :
[https://s31.postimg.org/xxemv39m3/Screenshot_from_2016_07_04_15_01_16.png]

Comment: Please, can you paste you full html file to get a better picture of what may be the issue?

Comment: yes you can see my html code in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pxesghog/
and soo i use the lasted version of firebase and angularfire

Comment: Ok, try pasting the firebase code snippet (as mentioned in point 2)  **before** all the script tags, that is before the script tag <script src="Js/uikit.min.js"></script>

Comment: please help me !! :(