# Conflict Updating Firebase SDK - Authentication

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

In application I have a problem with Firebase SDK.

I try to log in with Firebase. But I have a FirebaseError:

> Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new
>   Firebase Authentication SDKs available from
>   firebase.google.com/docs/auth

In build.gradle I have the newest Authentication:

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1' - despite this in my app during logging to app there shows this FirebaseError.

My dependencies in build.gradle(Module:app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'

/* Firebase SDK */
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'

/* Firebase UI */
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'

   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1"

/* For Google Play Services */

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
}
```

Does somebody have some suggestions how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38015939/3585278

Comment: Yes, I checked but I cannot remove "firebase-client:2.5.2+" because I use this in my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix the V2 SDK (firebase-client-android 2.5.2) and the V3 SDK (all of which you regarded as "Firebase UI"). You must definitely remove the V2 dependency and update your sources to use the new classes.

It's actually a simple, almost mechanical task.