# Unable to create user in Firebase using Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a user in firebase but everytime I call the `createUser` it has an error message - `Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/`

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<APP-NAME>.firebaseio.com");
        ref.createUser("test@abc.com", "123", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "create successful " + result.get("uid"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "create error " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

here's my dependencies used:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
```

And I already updated my Google play services and google repository to the latest version.

Comment: It's doubtful you will have any success mixing the legacy SDK 2.X with the new 9.X SDK.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38015939/4815718

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit: since your project was created on firebase.google.com, it can only use the Authentication SDKs from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/. Check the [documentation to create a email+password user under there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account).

Also see: [How to solve the error "Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010536/how-to-solve-the-error-projects-created-at-console-firebase-google-com-must-use)